# Python adding two values to list based on range number

Tags: python, list, range

Is there a way to append two different values based on the numbers in range?
I have to use range 500.
I have two values: 0 and 1.
I need to create a list where every fifth number is 0.

I thought about creating list of 500 numbers, and then replace every fith with 0, but I'm not sure how do to that also.

Comment: `[x if x%5 else 0 for x in range(500)]` ? `[bool(x%5) for x in range(500)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
spam = [1 if num % 5 else 0 for num in range(1, 501)]
```

Comment: If the user didn't know how to do this by themselves, throwing an answer with a list comprehension without any explanation or without the "dumb" for-loop version is not going to help them in the future.